# Adding a Custom Persian Date Picker to Formio in React

Tags: reactjs, formio

I'm working on a React project and need to integrate a custom Persian date picker into a Formio form. Unfortunately, the default date picker provided by Formio uses flat-picker, which does not support Persian date format.

I've been searching extensively online, but I couldn't find a suitable example or guide for integrating a custom Persian date picker with Formio in a React application.

Answer (score 1):

You should add your own custom component which renders Persian calendar, in order to do that, you can check out this sandbox :
[Implementing custom component into form-io](https://codesandbox.io/s/custom-formio-component-in-react-81qb6)

So the component you render , can be a date picker which shows Persian calendar with your own styles.

Comment: hi , thanks for your help .

I saw it now , but it has error when Im trying to toggle it .

its better to say how to create custom components like datePicker or Map or .... .

Comment: checkout the link I mentioned earlier , doesn't it help you out ?

Comment: @AliGoodarzi The question of how to create custom components like datePicker or Map or ..., really depends on what frameworks or library you want to implement inside the custom component (or of course, you could write all codes by yourself).

Comment: i asked the question for react .

Comment: Just check the link I mentioned in answer section ! there is the answer for you

Comment: Hi, I checked that link, but it didn't help.
I would be grateful if you could introduce me to an example that could work.
I did the calendar thing with another method, but now I need to add the map. I would be grateful if anyone could help me.

Comment: check this one out : 

https://formio.github.io/formio.js/app/examples/customcomponent.html